# how to change the color of text in actionbar, bydefault is coming black?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-titlebar

here the default color of text in actionbar is coming Black. I need the text to be color as White. How can change the color to default color black to white of my title in actiobar.

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.



-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.



    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/MyColor</item>
    <item name="background">@color/MyColor</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: posted style.xml is created by you?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom actionbar like this:

**custom_action_bar.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#526e83"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ContactImageId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CTS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="CTS"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/UserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Welcome: HKH"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in each **Activity** you can call this method in onCreate to set the actionBar to your custom ActionBar:

```
public void addTextToActionBar() {

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
        actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#526e83")));
        View cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
    }
```

and under res--> values --> styles change to this:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

i hope this will help

Comment: <!-- ActionBar styles for Text Style, Background -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#33B5E5</item>
        <item name="background">@color/MyColor</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>